# I can't get image to display using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Am working on a quiz where i need an image to show good or bad when i click submit, if the correct or wrong answers are chosen. But i keep getting only one image displayed.

HTML

```
<div class = "question1">
       <p>What is the capital of Nigeria?</p>
       <input type = "text" id = "question_one">
       <div id = "goodorbad"></div>

   </div>

   <div class = "question2">
       <p>Which of these is the symbol for 'plus'?</p>
       <select id = "operators">
           <option value = "x">x</option>
           <option value = "-">-</option>
           <option value = "+">+</option>
           <option value = "%">%</option>
       </select> 
       <div id = "goodorbad"></div>
   </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function getResult() {
let answer_one = document.getElementById("question_one").value;
let answer_two = document.getElementById("operators").value;
let correct_ans = 0;

if (answer_one === "abuja") {
    correct_ans++;

}

if (answer_two === "+") {
    correct_ans++;
} 


let sign_symbol = ["bad1.png" , "good1.png"];
let sign;



 if (correct_ans === true){
    sign = 1;
}
else{
    sign = 0;
} 

 document.getElementById("goodorbad").src = sign_symbol[sign];
```

If an answer is correct, then the good1.png image should display at the right hand corner and if an answer is incorrect, the bad1.png image should display

Comment: Where are you calling `getResult()` and how are you sending the form?

Comment: There is a submit button with onclick = "getResult()". I didn't add it.

Answer (score 2):

You're using a `src` attribute on a `div` instead of an `img` tag which won't work. Also, use a generic class e.g `question-img` for common elements, in this case the img tag rather than using the same id for multiple elements which is a bad practice.

```
<div class = "question1">
   <p>What is the capital of Nigeria?</p>
   <input type = "text" id = "question_one">
   <img class="question-img" src=""/>
 </div>
```

and use `document.querySelector` like to assign the `src` to the `img` element

```
 document.querySelector("#question1 .question-img").src = sign_symbol[sign];
```

Also your `if (correct_ans === true)` statement is always going to be false since you're comparing a number with a boolean.

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped a lot. But if my correct_ans === 1 is always going to be false, how do i get it to work

Comment: @Barri You can do something like `if ( correct_ans > 0 )` (means we have 1 or more correct answer ) then do some stuff that you want.

Comment: Do upvote and accept this as the answer if it helped :) Happy coding !

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple faults with your codes.

1. You have two questions but you are selecting the true if there is only 1 correct answer.
2. you have assigned `src` to `div` but it should be assigned to `img`.
3. the result of (`correct_ans === true`) is always false. Because three equal sign compares both values and types and a number type is never equal to boolan type.
4. You have multiple id of `goodorbad` and using ID selector, only selects the first occurance.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have multiple HTML elements with the same ID, they must be unique.

You should use [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) and/or data-attributes if you want to select multiple elements at the same time.